# Selenium webdriver 'command_executor' error

Tags: python, selenium

*Hey Everyone. This little script is driving me crazy so I am calling for backup.
When I run the script below it gives me*

## TypeError: **init**() got multiple values for argument 'command_executor'

*It would be nice if anyone could give me a hand.*

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time

# The main process calls this function to create the driver instance.
def createDriverInstance():
    options = Options()
    options.add_argument('--disable-infobars')
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'mypath',chrome_options=options)
    return driver

# Called by the second process only.
def secondProcess(executor_url, session_id):
    options = Options()
    options.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
    options.add_argument("--enable-file-cookies")
    capabilities = options.to_capabilities()
    same_driver = webdriver.Remote(r'mypath',command_executor=executor_url,desired_capabilities=capabilities)
    same_driver.close()
    same_driver.session_id = session_id
    same_driver.get("https://www.wikipedia.org")
    time.sleep(4)
    same_driver.quit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    driver = createDriverInstance()
    driver.get("https://google.com")
    time.sleep(2)

    # Pass the driver session and command_executor to the second process.
    secondProcess(driver.command_executor._url,driver.session_id)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

webdriver.Remote
[doesn't](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html?highlight=remote#module-selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver) have an argument for the path to the chromedriver file, so you don't have to use it.

So just change this line from this:

```py
same_driver = webdriver.Remote(r'mypath',command_executor=executor_url,desired_capabilities=capabilities)
```

to this:

```py
same_driver = webdriver.Remote(command_executor=executor_url,desired_capabilities=capabilities)
```